# duplicate comment section functionality and call it something else for custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, comments, comment-form

I have a custom post type that I want people to leave messages but I dont want to call it "comment". How can I replicate the comment functionality and call it something else for a custom post type?

I dont want these to show up on the general comment section of WordPress dashboard, something exactly like comments just for a custom post type.

Comment: So you have 2 questions, how do I implement a custom comments template for a particular post type with different language strings, and how do I show comments on a custom post type on a separate screen?

Comment: @TomJNowell yes, I want to have a comment template for custom post types and show those comments in the dashboard under the post type.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the core comment functionality for the custom post type, then filter the edit-comments.php admin screen and create a new admin page with the required comments table.

Step 1. **Removing the comments from the edit-comments.php admin screen** can be done by using the `comments_clauses` filter:

```
<?php

// Remove comments for specific post type ('project' in this case)
function exclude_comments_on_post_type( $clauses, $wp_comment_query ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( ! $wp_comment_query -> query_vars['post_type' ] ) {
        $clauses['where'] .= $wpdb->prepare( " AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_type != %s", 'project' );
    }
    return $clauses;
}

// Load the above only on the needed admin screen
function exclude_comments_on_post_type_hook( $screen ) {
    if ( $screen->id == 'edit-comments' ) {
        add_filter( 'comments_clauses', 'exclude_comments_on_post_type', 10, 2 );
    }    
}

// Execute the hook
add_action( 'current_screen', 'exclude_comments_on_post_type_hook', 10, 2 );
```

Step 2. In order to **display those comments elsewhere in the admin interface**, you'll need to create a new admin page using the `add_menu_page()` function and insert a custom WP_List_Table instance that will show the comments on that post type. Since it's a farily long read, I'll just post one of the links here without pasting all the details: https://www.sitepoint.com/using-wp_list_table-to-create-wordpress-admin-tables/